# 'Network link lost' - how can I see what causes it?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 pc connected to a home router via a wired connection. I use a 10G PCI express card for the network adapter. All other adapters are disabled.

Every 1h or so (its random) I lose connectivity. When I check the windows system event logs, I find the error

```
ASUS XG-C100C 10G PCI-E Network Adapter : Network link is lost.
```

5s later the link is reestablished. I can try rebooting everything etc, but I want to know more. Other devices on the same network do not experience the same issue.

How can I determine exactly what the cause is?

Comment: If this device is connected to a router, check the logs on the router, the problem likely exists with the router.

Comment: Unfortunately, my ISP have seen fit to deny me access to the router logs.

Comment: Turns out this card has very flaky drivers. Bumping the version fixed the disconnect issue, but unfortunately created new issues as it now throttles upload speed. Warranty time!